# Unusual completion of $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, formal-power-series

The $p$-adic norm $$\left|\sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n\right|= \sup_{n\le N} |a_n|_p$$
is an absolute value on $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$. The completion, call it $S_1$, is the ring of formal power series whose coefficients $\to 0$, equivalently it is the ring of $p$-adic analytic functions on the closed unit ball of $\Bbb{C}_p$ (this makes sense because it is open).

> The difference between analytic functions on the complex unit disk is that here $|f(\zeta)|_p$ is attained for all but finitely many roots of unity

$T_1=S_1[p^{-1}]$ is called "the Tate algebra in one variable" and [is a PID](https://web.archive.org/web/20060916051553/http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Ekedlaya//18.727/tate-algebras.pdf).

The fraction field $F_1=Frac(S_1)$ is the ring of meromorphic functions on the closed unit ball. The discrete valuation ring is $$O_{F_1}=\{ f\in F_1,|f|\le 1\}=(S_1-(p))^{-1} S_1$$ The residue field is $O_{F_1}/(p)=\operatorname{Frac}(\Bbb{F}_p[x])$.

> From either Krasner's lemma or Weierstrass preparation theorem we should obtain that the poles are algebraic so that $O_{F_1}= \Bbb{Z}_p[x]_{\text{monic}}^{-1}S_1$. Is it correct?
>
> Is there a description of the maximal unramified extension and the tamely ramified extensions of $F_1$? Of the automorphisms of $F_1$? What is the meaning of the extensions and reduction $\bmod p$ in term of analytic functions? Are there more weird absolute values on $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$? I'll take anything interesting to say about this ring.

Comment: I'm sure you are aware that for any positive $r$ you can take the norm $\sup \lbrace \lvert a_n \rvert_p r^n \rbrace$ and get the ring of functions on the closed ball of radius $r$? And then Laurent series, overconvergent series, the Robba ring?

Comment: I found some texts so I'll use their notations. From the keyword rigid analytic space I could find [Tate algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate_algebra) which with 1 variable is the ring $T_1$. [One of the links](https://web.archive.org/web/20060916051553/http://www-math.mit.edu/~kedlaya//18.727/tate-algebras.pdf) is mentioning that the norm is an absolute value and that $T_1$ is a PID (probably not surprising as being the completion of $\Bbb{Q}_p[x]$). He is proving my $O_{F_1}= \Bbb{Z}_p[x]_{monic}^{-1}S_1$ claim from Weierstrass preparation theorem @TorstenSchoeneberg

Comment: I learned that stuff years ago from [P. Schneider's lecture notes (chapters 9&10, German)](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/pschnei/publ/lectnotes/Theorie-des-Anstiegs.pdf). The original source for most of that is the [seminal paper by Lazard (French)](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1962__14__47_0.pdf). All those rings and their extensions feature in Fontaine's $p$-adic Hodge theory which is hot these days because of $p$-adic local Langlands.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I just realized there was a french one, tks, I'll come back in a few days. I don't know those topics. Do you think they tried to translate the theory of $p$-adic modular and $\theta$ functions, elliptic integrals, elliptic curves over $T_1$ instead of $\Bbb{Q}_p((x))$ ? It could change a lot of things